# onclick to go to javascript in chrome and opera

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I have a `javascript` that loads two files into two different iframes on the click event.  It used to work in all browsers but now in Opera 32.0 and Chrome version 46.0.2490.80 the onclick does nothing. It still works with IE.
Here is the function:

```
<script language="javascript">
    function loadTwo(iframe1URL, iframe2URL) 
    { 
    parent.upper.location.href=iframe1URL; 
    parent.dimensions.location.href=iframe2URL; 
    }; 
    </script>
```

"upper"and "dimensions" are the names of the iframes.

Here is the HTML:

```
 <a href="#" onclick="loadTwo('MyPrice-R33.htm','DimR-33.htm')">
    DCR-33</a><br>
    <a href="#" onclick="loadTwo('MyPrice-R44.htm','DimR-44.htm')">
    DCR-44</a><br>
    <a href="#" onclick="loadTwo('MyPrice-R66.htm','DimR-66.htm')">
    DCR-66</a><b>
```

Comment: The code part didn't work right I'll try again.

Comment: What are `parent.upper` and `parent.dimensions`?

Answer (score 0):

you can set src attribute of iframes with url.

```
function loadTwo(iframe1URL, iframe2URL) 
{ 
$("iframe1").attr("src",iframe1URL);
$("iframe2").attr("src",iframe2URL);
};
```

Comment: I guess this will solve the problem, give id to iframes and use $("#iframeid").attr("src",iframe1URL);

Comment: I get the error code, "The value of the property '$' is null or undefined, not a function object."

Comment: parent is the page that contains the frames.  upper and dimensions are the IDs of the frames.

Comment: You should include jQuery to your page or project not to get '$' is null or undefined, not a function object." error.